# Error 'not supported' in Ubuntu Software Install when installing Zoom on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, versions, zoom-meeting

I am a new Linux user, so today I decided on trying Ubuntu as my first Linux distribution. After updating and upgrading, I decided to start installing my usual applications, such as VLC, Skype and Zoom, but with the last one I got a problem.

I tried to install Zoom from the [original website](https://zoom.us/download#client_4meeting)

I have selected:

- Linux Type: Ubuntu
- OS Architecture: 64 bit (matches my CPU)
- Version: 16.04+; 12.04 (I put both of them, because I have tried both).

I tried to install them with the Ubuntu Software Install, and neither of them could be installed. The error:

> Failed to install file: not supported

I do not know if the names of the versions are versions of Zoom, or past versions of Ubuntu OS.

Thanks for reading, I would appreciate any help.

Have a great day.

Comment: What is the name of the file that you downloaded? Is it a .deb file? [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1275325/edit) the question to include this information.

Comment: Yes, it is a .deb file

Comment: Is the .deb file still in your Downloads directory? If not, exactly where did you move it to?

Comment: Yes, both of them are still in my Downloads directory

Comment: Delete the 12.04 version -- it won't help you. Open a terminal. Try `sudo apt install ~/Downloads/zoom_amd64.deb`. You might need to match the name carefully since you downloaded more than once. If it fails, add the complete output [to your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1275325/edit).

Comment: @user535733 It works, thank you so much, have a nice day.

Comment: @user535733 This should be an answer rather than a comment. It's simpler than the accepted answer, although snap does have the benefit of automatic updates.

Comment: Note this error also occurs when trying to update Zoom. It occurred to me with Ubuntu 20.04 but not with Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the GDebi tool and install the .deb file with it. It's the "original" GUI tool to install .deb files. For me, Ubuntu Software almost always failed to install offline .deb files.

**Edit:** I just noted that Ubuntu Software does not find GDebi by name. So you have to install it via terminal: `apt-get install gdebi`

The general description of it from `apt show gdebi` is:

> Description: simple tool to view and install deb files - GNOME GUI
> gdebi lets you install local deb packages resolving and installing
> its dependencies. apt does the same, but only for remote (http, ftp)
> located packages.
> The package is also scanned via lintian before the install and its
> possible to inspect the control and data members of the packages.
> This package contains the graphical user interface.

Comment: Remember to add sudo in front of command.  GDebi does seem to install some software better than other tools.  Just adding this since OP is new user.

Comment: In my case `gdebi` unpacked zoom (5.6.13632.0328) over (5.2.446620.0816) and threw a warning **/usr/bin/gdebi:113: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1 c = findall("[[(](\S+)/\S+[])]", msg)[0].lower()** and an error **Error in file "/usr/share/applications/org.kde.kdeconnect_open.desktop": "*/*" is an invalid MIME type ("*" is an unregistered media type)**. The installation proceeded nonetheless and I could launch the new version of Zoom. I haven't had any meeting to join yet for a smoke test, though.

Comment: In my view, this should be the accepted answer. Once `gedit` is installed, you may have to right click on the .deb file and do "Open with Other application" and then select "Gdebi" in the list

Answer (score 1):

You can also install `Zoom` via `snap`.
That will give you the added benefit of easy updating.

Either install in the terminal with

```
sudo snap install zoom-client
```

or get the GUI based `snap-store` with

```
sudo snap install snap-store
```

Then you will be able to update with

```
sudo snap refresh
```

or through the GUI store.

If you choose to install from the `.deb` file provided by `Zoom` directly then you will have to repeat the process for every update.